# Sharepoint UserProfileService

Tags: sharepoint, session, web-services

I've got a sharepoint site and a custom aspx portal, both under Windows Authentication.
With the same machine, it happens that my sharepoint site returning me my current login, while my custom aspx returning me my domain admin account instead.

Is there anyway that I could ensure both logins are the same? Otherwise, is there anyway to consume SPUserProfileService from a custom aspx portal?

Mainly, I need to have the custom aspx portal to get sharepoint logon id. Nevertheless, i could still trigger AccessDenied.aspx in sharepoint to prompt for logins.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Custom ASPX Portal", is it still hosted on the SharePoint Site?

In that case, how do you get the user? You can use SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser to get the user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are connecting from your custom aspx to SharePoint using your Domain Admin Account. 
Could you please describe more about your custom aspx portal and the way you are reading the username?

However, you can check my article (Even though it is for FBA users, you may find the code snippet useful):
[Possible ways to get logged in User Name & Handling Changes in FBA Users' Names if Membership Provider Name Changed](http://practicalsharepoint2010.blogspot.com/2012/02/logged-in-username-sharepoint-2010.html)

```
public string GetFlatUserName()
{
    //First, be sure that the user is not anonymous user:
    if (SPContext.Current == null || SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser == null)
        return "Anonymous";
    //Second, parse it:
    else
    {
        string flatUserName = this.Page.User.Identity.Name;
        if (flatUserName.Contains("\\"))
        {
            flatUserName = flatUserName.Substring(flatUserName.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
        }
        else if (flatUserName.Contains("|"))
        {
            flatUserName = flatUserName.Substring(flatUserName.IndexOf("|") + 1);
        }
        return flatUserName;
    }
}
```